# Stop page going to top on checkbox click (image with text appearing below)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, checkbox

I am trying to achieve a css solution to the below:

https://jsfiddle.net/slinger55/fdL8xrk8/3/

```css
#toggle{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
span{
  display: none;
}
#toggle:checked + span{
  display: block;
}
img{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle">
  <img style="width: 100%" src="http://i.imgur.com/pOFyUBh.png" />
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<span>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam varius bibendum turpis, ac viverra libero scelerisque sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ipsum metus, dictum in feugiat sit amet, finibus vitae tortor. Cras vestibulum magna vel enim elementum, nec elementum risus mattis. Sed sodales velit vitae elit sagittis convallis vulputate non erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer et dictum arcu. Duis sed efficitur massa, sit amet pulvinar ante. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce interdum felis at ligula semper, sit amet aliquam ex venenatis. Etiam feugiat pellentesque dapibus.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam varius bibendum turpis, ac viverra libero scelerisque sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ipsum metus, dictum in feugiat sit amet, finibus vitae tortor. Cras vestibulum magna vel enim elementum, nec elementum risus mattis. Sed sodales velit vitae elit sagittis convallis vulputate non erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer et dictum arcu. Duis sed efficitur massa, sit amet pulvinar ante. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce interdum felis at ligula semper, sit amet aliquam ex venenatis. Etiam feugiat pellentesque dapibus.</p>

</span>
```

Whenever I click the image to show the text, the page jumps to the top. This is embedded on a Wordpress page so would like to stick to css only if possible. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the page jumping to the top (even when I tested by adding a few extra paragraphs above the image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The reason is because of the unusual value given to the checkbox(`#toggle`). `position: absolute` takes the element out of the document itself giving you the freedom to place it anywhere on the page using `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` properties. In your case you have placed it at the VERY top of the document by giving it `top: -9999px; left: -9999px;`. So everytime you click the label(or the `img`) it **jumps to the checkbox**(placed at the VERY top).

**Solution:**

Reduce the `top` & `left` values **OR** even better use any other methods like `visibility: hidden` **OR** `display: none` to hide the checkbox rather than pushing to the very end of the document itself.

```
#toggle{
  position: absolute; /* remove */
  top: -9999px; /* remove */
  left: -9999px; /* remove */
  display: none; /* OR -> visibility: hidden; */
}
```

```css
#toggle{
  display: none;
}
span{
  display: none;
}
#toggle:checked + span{
  display: block;
}
img{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle">
  <img style="width: 100%" src="http://i.imgur.com/pOFyUBh.png" />
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<span>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam varius bibendum turpis, ac viverra libero scelerisque sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ipsum metus, dictum in feugiat sit amet, finibus vitae tortor. Cras vestibulum magna vel enim elementum, nec elementum risus mattis. Sed sodales velit vitae elit sagittis convallis vulputate non erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer et dictum arcu. Duis sed efficitur massa, sit amet pulvinar ante. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce interdum felis at ligula semper, sit amet aliquam ex venenatis. Etiam feugiat pellentesque dapibus.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam varius bibendum turpis, ac viverra libero scelerisque sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ipsum metus, dictum in feugiat sit amet, finibus vitae tortor. Cras vestibulum magna vel enim elementum, nec elementum risus mattis. Sed sodales velit vitae elit sagittis convallis vulputate non erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer et dictum arcu. Duis sed efficitur massa, sit amet pulvinar ante. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce interdum felis at ligula semper, sit amet aliquam ex venenatis. Etiam feugiat pellentesque dapibus.</p>

</span>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and so simple! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cheers .. Accept the answer so it can help others as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this  to the span element.It will fix the issue

Comment: I have added only <span for = "toggle" > to the span.